# What does it mean forecast horizon in time series forecasting?

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, lstm

I'm a beginner in time series forecasting and I'm not sure if I understood correctly the meaning of forecast horizon.
I was considering horizons as points in the future for which we would like to predict a value. For example, a horizon of 30 days would, in my approach, means that we want to predict the 30th value of a time series. And I'm not interested in knowing the other points before this one.
But in some works, forecast horizons are considered as the set of points in the future that we want to predict. In this case, a horizon of 30 days means that we want to predict the values of the 30 days in the future.

Which meaning is the correct one? Or both alternatives are correct?

Bst regards.

Comment: The latter definition -- if your forecast horizon is 30, you're forecasting 30 steps ahead

Comment: @BenA And there is some name for the former definition?

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled upon this question by looking for something similar; here's what I know:

Your question highlights two different types of forecasting:

1. **Point Forecast:** In this interpretation, a forecast horizon of 30 days means predicting the value of the time series on the 30th day
   in the future. This approach is used when you only care about a
   specific point in time.
2. **Multi-Step Forecast:** In this interpretation, a forecast horizon of 30 days means predicting the values for all 30 days in the
   future. There are two main types of multi-step forecasting:

   - **Direct Multi-step Forecast:** Separate models are created for each step in the forecast horizon, e.g., one model for predicting the value one day ahead, another for two days ahead, and so on, up to 30 days ahead.
   - **Iterative (Recursive) Multi-step Forecast:** A single model is used to iteratively predict future values. The model predicts the value one step ahead, and then this predicted value is fed back into the model to predict the value two steps ahead, and so on.

Both interpretations are correct and correspond to different types of forecasting. The choice of approach depends on your specific use case and requirements.

Indeed, there are several other multi-step forecasting methods that may be relevant depending on your problem and dataset. You can find more information on various multi-step forecasting techniques in this article: https://towardsdatascience.com/6-methods-for-multi-step-forecasting-823cbde4127a

I hope this helps!